# Microsoft Word how to turn off Proofing FOREVER

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-365

In Word (365 in my case, but this is in all versions that I've used), there are lots of ways to stop spell/grammar check.  For example: go to *File*->*Options*->*Proofing*, scroll to the bottom and uncheck *Hide spelling errors* and/or *Hide grammar errors*. You have the option for choosing "just this document" or "all new documents" (the *all new documents* option doesn't seem to do anything that I can tell).

What I can't find is the **opposite**:  I'd like spell/grammar check to be *always* off with the option to turn it on if I need it -- new documents, old documents, documents from the future, whatever.

To emphasize: when creating a new document, I'd like spell/grammar check to be disabled automatically, without the user having to do anything.

Is this functionality supported in Microsoft Word 365?  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Consider trying the following steps: [1] back up NORMAL.DOT/NORMAL.DOTX [2] create a blank document [3] Turn off proofing for all documents [4] save your blank document with proofing off as a Document Template [5] Exit Word and copy your newly-saved template to NORMAL.DOT/NORMAL.DOTX

Comment: **No. You cannot create a fully functional normal template that way.** Even if your normal template is set to have no checking, this has no effect on existing documents, only new ones based on that template. You could create no-proofing styles and save those in the existing normal.dotm. You could modify the normal style to no-proofing and save that in the normal template. See https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/creating-no-proofing-styles-in-microsoft-word-no/999c8de4-dac2-4fac-be07-ab55e8d636cc